# C - Merging two lists of strings

Tags: c, list

I currently have this algorithm:

```
char** mergeLists(char **a, char **b, int sizeA, int sizeB, int *lSize)
{
    char **list = malloc( sizeof(char *) );
    int pA = 0, pB = 0, listSize = 0;

    while (pA != sizeA && pB != sizeB)
    {
        list = realloc(list, sizeof(char *) * (++listSize) );

        if (strcmp(a[pA], b[pB]) < 0)
        {
            list[listSize-1] = a[pA];
            pA++;                
        }
        else
        {   
            list[listSize-1] = b[pB];
            pB++;   
        }    
    }

    *lSize = listSize;

    return list;
}
```

But it appears to have some error. I'm currently running this test:

```
char *l1[6];
l1[0] = "a";
l1[1] = "b";
l1[2] = "c";
l1[3] = "d";
l1[4] = "e";
l1[5] = "f";

char *l2[6];
l2[0] = "aa";
l2[1] = "ba";
l2[2] = "ca";
l2[3] = "da";
l2[4] = "ea";
l2[5] = "fa";

int s;
char **l = mergeLists(l1, l2, 6, 6, &s);

int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < s; i++)
    printf("%s\n", l[i]);
```

It is printing:

```
a
aa
b
ba
c
ca
d
da
e
ea
f
```

The last item of the second list is missing. I think it could be some mistake in the condition of the while loop.

I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Comment: Also, you know how big the destination array needs to be.  There's no need to `malloc` and then `realloc` each time...!

Comment: This is not the source of your error, but you should really use `size_t` for array lengths, string lengths, array indices, object sizes, anything you plan to pass to `malloc` or get from `sizeof` and `strlen`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I would call this merging two *lists* of strings, but two *arrays* of strings. Other than that, the answer has already been provided.

Answer (score 6):

Your code only runs up to the first end of either of the lists. You need to add two more loops at the end to include the values that remain in the list that hasn't been consumed fully.

Comment: What if I change the while loop condition to while(pA != sizeA || pB != sizeB)? I already tried that, but pA reaches the value of 7 and there's a segfault...

Comment: You would have to supplement the conditions inside the loop to look for exhaustion of one of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

fix like this:

```
char** mergeLists(char **a, char **b, int sizeA, int sizeB, int *lSize){
    char **list = NULL;
    int pA = 0, pB = 0, listSize = 0;
    int emptyA = 0, emptyB = 0;

    while (pA != sizeA || pB != sizeB){
        list = realloc(list, sizeof(char *) * (++listSize) );

        if(emptyA){
            list[listSize-1] = b[pB++];
            continue;
        }
        if(emptyB){
            list[listSize-1] = b[pA++];
            continue;
        }
        if (strcmp(a[pA], b[pB]) < 0){
            list[listSize-1] = a[pA++];
            if(pA == sizeA)
                emptyA = 1;
        }
        else{
            list[listSize-1] = b[pB++];
            if(pB == sizeB)
                emptyB = 1;
        }
    }

    *lSize = listSize;

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **merge_arrays(char **arrA, char **arrB, size_t sizeA, size_t sizeB, size_t *lSize)
{
    size_t idxA , idxB , idxDst ;
    char **result ;

    result = malloc( (sizeA+sizeB) * sizeof *result );
    if (!result) return NULL;

    for(idxA=idxB=idxDst=0; idxA < sizeA && idxB < sizeB; )
    {
        if (strcmp(arrA[idxA], arrB[idxB]) <= 0) result[idxDst++] = arrA[idxA++];
        else result[idxDst++] = arrB[idxB++];
    }

    if (idxA < sizeA) {
        memcpy (result+idxDst, arrA+idxA, (sizeA-idxA) * sizeof *result);
        idxDst += sizeA-idxA;
        }
    else if (idxB < sizeB) {
        memcpy (result+idxDst, arrB+idxB, (sizeB-idxB) * sizeof *result);
        idxDst += sizeB-idxB;
        }

    *lSize = idxDst;

    return result;
}
```